# running gRPC server and client on different machine

Tags: python, server, grpc, rpc, grpc-python

Currently I am using below code to start a grpc server, I want to start graph server and client in such a way so that I would be able to run both on different machines and then connecting them.

```
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
xyz_pb2_grpc.add_xyzServicer_to_server(
    xyzServicer(), server
)
server.add_insecure_port("localhost:50051")
server.start()
print("server started")
server.wait_for_termination()
```

I used the above approach to connect both server and client on same machine but now I want to do it with server and client on different machine

Comment: you are binding to "localhost" aka 127.0.0.1  which is only useable within that same machine. You could probably bind grpc to "0.0.0.0" which means the server will listen on all available IPs the device has but you also need to know what is the IP of that server in the cliebt side.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

As @rasjani said, use `0.0.0.0:50051` or ipV4 or `[::]:50051` for ipV6.  You can look at the basic tutorial at https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/basics/#starting-the-server